# Return filtered JSON response with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to return a filtered JSON response using jQuery after a successful GET request of the original JSON response. The original JSON response is an array of our products within our Shopify store for the given collection page the user is on. I am trying to filter the full JSON response down to a new JSON response that filters out all products that don't contain the tag the user has selected from a dropdown. The tag the user selected is the input of the getFilterProducts function.

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
    products: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "white shirt",
            "tags": [
                "small"
                "medium"
                "large"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "black shirt",
            "tags": [
                "medium"
                "large"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "blue shirt",
            "tags": [
                "small"
                "medium"
                "large"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code for the jQuery GET:

```
function getFilterProducts(tag){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: coll_url + '/products.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res){
          var productArray = $(res.products).filter(function() {
              return res.products.tags === tag;
          });
          console.log(productArray);
        },
        error: function(status){
             alert(status);
        }
    })
}
```

So if a users selected the tag "Small" from the dropdown, it should find which products have the tag "Small" and return a new JSON response with just the White and Blue shirt in it.

I feel like I am close but just can't wrap my head around why the response keeps coming back empty for every tag.

Comment: Have you tried `res.products.filter` instead of `$(res.products).filter`? in jQuery `$()` is a function wrapper for DOM selectors (usually).

Comment: Also, your Arrays items are missing commas `,` but I guess that's a typo for the sake of [mcve]

Comment: `getFilterProducts` does not return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery.inArray()`

```
var productArray = res.products.filter(function(product) {
              return jQuery.inArray(tag, product.tags) !== -1;

});
```

```js
var res = {
  products: [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "white shirt",
      "tags": [
        "small",
        "medium",
        "large"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "black shirt",
      "tags": [
        "medium",
        "large"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "blue shirt",
      "tags": [
        "small",
        "medium",
        "large"
      ]
    }
  ]
};
tag = 'small';
var productArray = res.products.filter(function(product) {
  return jQuery.inArray(tag, product.tags) !== -1;
});

console.log( productArray );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JS's (not jQuery's) [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const res = {
  products: [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "white shirt",
      "tags": [
        "small",
        "medium",
        "large",
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "black shirt",
      "tags": [
        "medium",
        "large",
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "blue shirt",
      "tags": [
        "small",
        "medium",
        "large",
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const tag = "small";
const productArray = res.products.filter(item => item.tags.includes(tag));
console.log(productArray);
```

Here's a small reminder of what jQuer `.filter()` does and how it works: https://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: Your json is malformed. The following has been correct:

```
{
  "products": [ 
       {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "white shirt",
         "tags": [
                 "small",
                 "medium",
                 "large"
         ]
       },
       {
         "id": 2,
         "title": "black shirt",
         "tags": [
                 "medium",
                 "large"
         ]
       },
       {
         "id": 3,
         "title": "blue shirt",
         "tags": [
                 "small",
                 "medium",
                 "large"
         ]
       }
    ]
}
```

**Here is the code you are looking for:**

*We check for every product that the tag list contains the tag we want.*

*Call the *filterProducts* function when the ajax operation succeeded. I cut the ajax part for demonstration purposes.*

```js
const JSON_DATA = JSON.parse(`{"products":[{"id":1,"title":"white shirt","tags":["small","medium","large"]},{"id":2,"title":"black shirt","tags":["medium","large"]},{"id":3,"title":"blue shirt","tags":["small","medium","large"]}]}`);

const TAG = "small";

function filterProducts(json_products, tag) {
   if(json_products === undefined || tag === undefined) return [];
   
   return json_products.products.filter((product) =>
       product.tags.includes(tag)
   );
}

console.log(filterProducts(JSON_DATA, TAG));
```

Hope it helps :)